# javascript delete clone node parent table

Tags: javascript, clonenode

I am trying to delete the parent of a clone node in JavaScript because when i restore the saved table it creates a duplicate of the same table below the original. So I need to delete the original table and just display the child table.

```
function Save(){
var table = document.getElementById("sudoku");
clone = table.cloneNode(true);  
}
//Create Restore Function
function Restore(){
document.getElementById("sudoku").parentNode.appendChild(clone);
table.parentNode.removeChild("table");
}
```

I have also tried this method I found on here on another thread but when I try use it stops the rest of my javascript working

```
document.getElementById("sudoku").parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById‌​("sudoku"));
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function Restore(){
    var table = document.getElementById("sudoku"),
        parent = table.parentNode;
    parent.removeChild(table);
    parent.appendChild(clone);
}
```

Note that listeners may be on the table that was removed so you could have to re-attach them.

Comment: The event listeners aren't attached to the new elements

Comment: The original table is deleted which is perfect but the child table is no longer editable. Is there a way to fix this or is it a problem from using cloneNode itself?

Comment: how would you go about reattaching the event listeners. sorry I'm pretty new to javascript

Comment: It may be easier to do the backup and restore in a different way, looping over each square.

Comment: How would you go about doing this though? Instead of using a cloneNode use a 2d array?

Comment: Yes, or even a 3D array depending on how much data needs to be restored (i.e. if it is more than just current value, such as possible values)